# How can I execute a console function but from the browser in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser, console

I'm trying to execute this function but in the terminal with Node.JS

```
var WebTorrent = require('webtorrent')

var client = new WebTorrent()

var magnetURI = 'magnet: ...'

client.add(magnetURI, { path: '/path/to/folder' }, function (torrent) {
  torrent.on('done', function () {
    console.log('torrent download finished')
  })
})
```

I mean, for example, create an `<button>` tag, and when is clicked,
that the previous function be executed in the nodejs console, not in the browser console.

EXTRA:
I'm executing this two files: 
app.js

```
let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            respone.write('Whoops! File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
};

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

And

index.html that contains the `<button>` tag but does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Client(browser) and server are two different entities, when client is browser the only way to communicate is through HTTP protocol, in simple terms use internet.

Now browser understand only it's own kind of javascript, more precisely ECMA but not nodejs. So the following code could not be executed in browser

```
var WebTorrent = require('webtorrent')

var client = new WebTorrent()
```

Hence I would assume it is running on server which your machine and hence `console.log` will print to your terminal.

To run it on browser, I assume you will have to code it differently, either you will have to use `browserify` and analyze the client side script **OR** code only in client side with below libaray :

```
<script src="webtorrent.min.js"></script>
```

For more details refer, complete web page example at https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent/blob/master/docs/get-started.md